# Convert Ruby array of elements to Hash of counts with indices

Tags: ruby

Given a two dimensional array in Ruby:

```
[ [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1]
]
```

I'd like to create a Hash, where the keys are the counts of each internal array, and the values are arrays of indices of the original array whose internal array sizes have the particular count. The resulting Hash would be:

```
{ 2 => [1, 3], 3 => [0], 4 => [2] }
```

How do I concisely express this functionally in Ruby? I am attempting something akin to `Hash.new([]).tap { |h| array.each_with_index { |a, i| h[a.length] << i } }`, but the resulting Hash is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that when `h` is empty and you write, say, `h[2] << 1`, since `h` does not have a key `2`, `h[2]` returns the default, so this expression becomes `[] << 1 #=> [1]`, but `[1]` is not attached to the hash, so no key and value are added.

You need to write `h[2] = h[2] << 1`<sup>1</sup>. If you do that, your code returns `h #=> {3=>[0, 1, 2, 3], 2=>[0, 1, 2, 3], 4=>[0, 1, 2, 3]}`. Unfortunately, that's still incorrect, which takes us to the second problem with your code: you did not define the newly-created hash's default value correctly.

First note that

```
h[3].object_id
  #=> 70113420279440 
h[2].object_id
  #=> 70113420279440 
h[4].object_id
  #=> 70113420279440
```

Aha, all three values are the same object! `new`'s argument `[]` is returned by `h[k]` when `h` does not have a key `k`. The problem is that is the *same array* is returned for all keys `k` added to the hash, so you would be adding a key-value pair to an empty array for the first new key, then adding a second key-value pair to that *same* array for the next new key, and so on. See below for how the hash needs to be defined.

With these two changes your code works fine, but I would suggest writing it as follows.

```
arr = [ [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1] ]

arr.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |(a,i),h|
  h[a.size] << i }
  #=> {3=>[0], 2=>[1, 3], 4=>[2]}
```

which use the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that uses a block to calculate the hash's *default value* (i.e., the value returned by `h[k]` when a hash `h` does not have a key `k`),

or

```
arr.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(a,i),h| (h[a.size] ||= []) << i }
  #=> {3=>[0], 2=>[1, 3], 4=>[2]}
```

both of which are effectively the following:

```
h = {}
arr.each_with_index do |a,i|
  sz = a.size
  h[sz] = [] unless h.key?(sz)
  h[a.size] << i
end
h #=> {3=>[0], 2=>[1, 3], 4=>[2]}
```

Another way is to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), grouping on array size, after picking up the index for each inner array.

```
h = arr.each_with_index.group_by { |a,i| a.size }
  #=> {3=>[[[1, 1, 1], 0]],
  #    2=>[[[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1], 3]],
  #    4=>[[[1, 1, 1, 1], 2]]} 
h.each_key { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) }
  #=> {3=>[0], 2=>[1, 3], 4=>[2]}
```

<sup>1 The expression `h[2] = h[2] << 1` uses the methods [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and  [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), which is why `h[2]` on the left of `=` does not return the default value. This expression can alternatively be written `h[2] ||= [] << 1`</sup>.

Comment: Ah, so that's how you chain it. I was trying `arr.with_object` first, and failing.

Comment: Very useful the `#with_object`, which avoids the code smell I used in my answer, declaring the hash out of the block. Thanks once more, Cary. It is a privilege having the chance of learning from a master like you.

Comment: @ybakos `with_object` only works with Enumerator objects. Or you could say the Array class has no method `with_object` defined.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 `with_object` is for `Enumerator`s but there is `Array#each_with_object` (and `Enumerable#each_with_object`). Similarly for `with_index` vs `each_with_index`.

Answer (score 3):

```
arry = [ [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1]
       ]

h = {}
arry.each_with_index do |el,i|
  c = el.count
  h.has_key?(c) ? h[c] << i : h[c] = [i]
end

p h
```

This will give you

```
{3=>[0], 2=>[1, 3], 4=>[2]}
```